# <form:error> not printing message

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-validator

Here is my code. Can someone please help?I have tried everything available on internet. I have changed my code in reference to many sites but in vain.  i have been searching for the answer from a long time but didn't find anything. Please help

Bean class

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;

    @Column
    @NotEmpty (message="First Name cannot be blank")
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    @Email(message="Email Id is not valid")
    private String email;

    @Column
    private int age;

    @Column
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column
    private boolean isAdmin = true;

    @Column
    @Size(min=3 , max = 10,message="Username should be between 3 to 10 characters long")
    private String userName;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String dob;

    @Column
    private boolean isActive;

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public boolean isAdmin() {
        return isAdmin;
    }

    public void setAdmin(boolean isAdmin) {
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return isActive;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean isActive) {
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserVo [userId=" + userId + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email
                + ", age=" + age + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + ", isAdmin=" + isAdmin + ", userName=" + userName
                + ", password=" + password + ", dob=" + dob + ", isActive=" + isActive + "]";
    }
}
```

Spring-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ism"></context:component-scan>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>

</bean>
    <bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
</bean>

<!-- DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://EHRRCMDEV:2433" />
    <property name="username" value="OMDTrainee" />
    <property name="password" value="Pass@OMDTrainee" />
</bean>
<!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.ism.vo.UserVo</value>
            <value>com.ism.vo.CategoryVo</value>
            <value>com.ism.vo.ItemVo</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Jsp File

```
<tr>
<td>Email:</td>
<td><form:input path="email"/><font color="red"><form:errors path="email"></form:errors></font></td>
</tr>
```

Message.properties

```
NotEmpty.userVo.firstName=First Name is required
Email.userVo.email= Email addesss is not valid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your snippet and added below code to fulfill your requirement. It is showing validation messages.

`@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String testMethodPost(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid @ModelAttribute("Bean") Bean bean, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.bean", result);
        model.addAttribute("bean", bean);
        return "MyJsp";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Can you include your Controller and jsp? There must be error in bean definition.
snippets that i need are :  *@Requestmethod.Get* that returns your form, the declaration of *< form:form>* tag, and method that handles incoming request *@Requestmethod.Post*

Comment: Thank You for replying but i got my ans in Mhod Yasin's reply